# Using concurrent.futures to call a fn in parallel every second

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I've been trying to get to grips with how I can use concurrent.futures to call a function 3 times every second, without waiting for it to return. I will collect the results after I've made all the calls I need to make.

Here is where I am at the moment, and I'm surprised that sleep() within this example function prevents my code from launching the next chunk of 3 function calls. I'm obviously not understanding the documentation well enough here :)

```
def print_something(thing):
    print(thing)
    time.sleep(10)

# define a generator 
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""    
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def main():    
    chunk_number = 0
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    for current_chunk in chunks(alphabet, 3):  # Restrict to calling the function 3 times per second
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:        
            futures = { executor.submit(print_something, thing): thing for thing in current_chunk }
            chunk_number += 1            
            print('chunk %s' % chunk_number)
            time.sleep(1)            
        
    for result in as_completed(futures): 
        print(result.result())
```

This code results in chunks of 3 being printed with a sleep time of 10s between each chunk.How can I change this to ensure I'm not waiting for the function to return before calling for the next batch ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some of your output.

Comment: @Algebra8 Sure - I get `chunk1 a b c` followed by 10s delay and then `chunk2 d e f` and so on.

Comment: And you're expecting to get them all without waiting at line `for result in as_completed`?

Comment: I don't care when I receive the results - I care about making sure that every second that function gets called 3 times. The sleep() call in print_something() is just to see what happens if the function takes a long time to respond (mimicking a slow network connection etc..). I don't want the execution time of the function to slow down the rate at which it is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for each iteration of `for current_chunk in chunks(alphabet, 3):`, you are creating a new `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance and `futures` dictionary instance clobbering the previous one. So the final loop `for result in as_completed(futures):` would only be printing the results from the last chunk submitted. Second, and the reason why I believe you are hanging, your block that is governed by `with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:` will not terminate until the tasks that are submitted by the `executor` are completed and that will take at least 10 seconds. So, the next iteration of the `for current_chunk in chunks(alphabet, 3):` block won't be executed more frequently than once every 10 seconds.

Note also that the block `for result in as_completed(futures):` needs to be moved within the `with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=26) as executor:` block for the same reason. That is, if it is placed after, it will not be executed until all the tasks have completed and so you will not be able to get results "as they complete."

You need to do a bit of rearranging as shown below (I have also modified `print_something` to return something other than `None`. There should be no hangs now if you have enough workers (26) to run the 26 tasks being submitted. I doubt your desktop (if you are running this on your PC) has 26 cores to support 26 *concurrently* executing processes. But I note that `print_something` only prints a short string and then sleeps for 10 seconds, which allows it to relinquish its processor to another process in the pool. So, while with cpu-intensive tasks, little is to be gained by specifying a `max_workers` value greater than the number of actual physical processors/cores you have on your computer, in this case it's OK. But more efficient when you have tasks that spend little time executing actual Python byte code is to use threading instead of processes, since the cost of creating threads is much less than the cost of creating processes. However, threading is notoriously poor when the tasks you are running largely consists of Python byte code since such code cannot be executed concurrently due to serialization of the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).

*Topic for you to research: The Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and Python byte code execution*

**Update to use threads:**

So we should substitute the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 26 or more light-weight threads for the `ProcessPoolExecutor`. The beauty of the `concurrent.futures` module is that no other code needs to be changed. But most important is to change the block structure and have a single `executor`.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

def print_something(thing):
    # NOT cpu-intensive, so threads should work well here
    print(thing)
    time.sleep(10)
    return thing # so there is a non-None result
    

# define a generator
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def main():
    chunk_number = 0
    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    futures = {}
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=26) as executor:
        for current_chunk in chunks(alphabet, 3):  # Restrict to calling the function 3 times per second
            futures.update({executor.submit(print_something, thing): thing for thing in current_chunk })
            chunk_number += 1
            print('chunk %s' % chunk_number)
            time.sleep(1)

        # needs to be within the executor block else it won't run until all futures are complete    
        for result in as_completed(futures):
            print(result.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The outcome is still not what I expect though - I get the following now `chunk 1
a
b
c
chunk 2
chunk 3
chunk 4
chunk 5
chunk 6
chunk 7
chunk 8
chunk 9
p
d
e
f
g
h
` With delays interspersed between the results. Any ideas ?

Comment: You're really not being clear what you are trying to accomplish. Now you have 3 total processors working on 27 "tasks". There *has* to be delays. Before the change, you were creating multiple pools of 3 processes each **or at least trying to**. But my desktop PC only has 8 cores, so the maximum level of multiprocessing I will get is 8, so eventually something has to wait. Change your code to use threads by replacing `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and specifying `max_workers=27` or more. Then let it run. You can use threads since your tasks are I/O bound (they mostly wait).

Comment: WIth the latest change I am now getting what I expected. With the first version of your solution, I was expecting to see 3 chunks being printed immediately (one for each of the 3 workers that ProcessPoolExplorer was initialized with, before seeing the delay. I'm not sure why that didn't happen with your first solution. Thanks for your help on this

Comment: I have rethought the issue and I believe I have a better explanation for what caused the original problem. See the updated answer.